# How to multiply many gpuArray matrices in parallel?

Tags: matlab, gpu

Given the matrices *A<sub>1</sub>,...,A<sub>n</sub>* and *B<sub>1</sub>,...,B<sub>n</sub>* stored as `gpuArray`, I want to calculate the matrices *C<sub>i</sub>=A<sub>i</sub>*B<sub>i</sub>*.

All *A<sub>i</sub>*'s are of the same size, and all *B<sub>i</sub>*'s are of the same (possibly different) size.

How do I do this fast on the GPU, assuming that *n* is very large and the sizes of the matrices are relatively small? Is it possible to avoid using CUDA?

Comment: why can't you just multiply them? if you have them as gpu arrays already, just multiply them and MATLAB will handle everything else, unless I am not understanding your question correctly

Comment: Also, what is the need for the GPU multiplication, MATLAB's standard multiplication with regular matrices is pretty darn fast as it is

Comment: The thing is that n (the amount of matrices) can be relatively large and the dimensions of each matrix can be relatively small. So the straight forward way will be serial in n.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have MATLAB R2013b, you can use the new gpuArray [`pagefun`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/distcomp/pagefun.html) function.

Answer (score 1):

If `A` and `B` are of class `gpuArray`, then the operation `C = A*B` will be carried out on the GPU without you needing to do anything else. You don't need to write any CUDA. The result `C` will also be a `gpuArray`, and you can bring it back to a normal array `D` in the local workspace with `D = gather(C)`.

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question for clarity - my n is large and each matrix size is small.